# Quadratic optimization: Why does the formula have "$\frac{1}{2}"$ in front?

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming

$$\frac{1}{2}x^THx+c^Tx + c_0$$

I have just formulated a problem as a quadratic optimization problem in two variables. My solution differs from the solution manual in the aspect that they have, **only** in front of the quadratic term, a coefficient $\frac{1}{2}$. Why is that there? Doesn't this change the equation?

For example:

I had two lines that are not parallel $L_1$, $L_2$ and I am supposed to find two points where the length is the smallest possible.

$$x = a + \alpha u$$ 
$$y = b + \beta v$$

where $a,b,u,v$ are known vectors in $R^3$ and $\alpha, \beta$ are in $R$

The final answer is

$$2x^THx+2c^Tx + c_0$$

The solution gives

$$x^THx+2c^Tx + c_0$$

Even if it is easier to differentiate, it just feels "illegal" to divide. Doesn't the equation change?

Comment: Usually the $\frac12$ is due to the fact that it vanishes when differentiating w.r.t $x$.

Comment: Yes it is because of convenience when solving the problem differentiating and setting $= 0$.

Comment: I have updated my question! :)

Comment: The constant term $2c^T$ will vanish when differentiating wrt x. If you have terms like $c^TMx$ or $x^TMc$ those will be affected by a factor 2 difference.